# PyQt global name '...' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, pyqt, global

I tried to solved this bug for two hours and searched every possible forum before I turned to posting a thread here.

The error that is occurring is in line 38

```
self.statusBar().showMessage(inputt)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial

In this example, we determine the event sender
object.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com
last edited: October 2011
"""

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)


        inputt = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        self.statusBar()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage(inputt)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you really think that anyone is interested in counting your lines?

Comment: what is global?

Comment: Please edit your question after reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "The error that is occurring" What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue, you defined `usernameEdit` and `passwordEdit` in `initui` but you are calling them in another method.

You should change them as attributes of the class to be able to use them anywhere :

```
self.usernameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
self.passwordEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
```

and then you can call them with the method `.text()` to get the input text :

```
if(try_username == self.usernameEdit.text() and try_password == self.passwordEdit.text() ):
```

Comment: `try_username` is string and `self.usernameEdit` is QLineEdit.

Comment: It is not congruent what you propose.

Comment: @eyllanesc, yeah... i didn't see this, thanks for pointing that